# How to test a TYPE's send and receive functions in regresssion test in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I create a new type mytype in PostgreSQL according to https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtype.html with send and receive functions as mytype_send and mytype_receive.

However, I don't know how to make sure I implemented those functions correctly. I'd like to add some functions to test them in my regression test, or at least cover them in my coverage test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`COPY ... (FORMAT binary)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) uses the type's send/receive functions to serialise/deserialise data.

For example, running this command:

```
COPY (SELECT '!!!'::text) TO '/tmp/test.bin' (FORMAT binary)
```

...will produce this output:

[image]

You can use this to check that the `send` output is correct.

You can also load this data back into the server to test the `receive` function, e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp (val text);
COPY tmp FROM '/tmp/test.bin' (FORMAT binary);
SELECT * FROM t WHERE val = '!!!';
```

Note that `COPY ... TO '<filename>'` assumes you have access to the server's file system. If you're running your tests from a client application, you probably want to use `COPY ... TO STDOUT` and access the data stream through your driver (e.g. [PGConnection.getCopyAPI()](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/PGConnection.html#getCopyAPI--) in pgJDBC).

It's worth mentioning that there is a much simpler way of testing the `send` function. As it returns a `bytea` value, it can be called directly from SQL:

```
SELECT textsend('!!!'::text) = '\x212121'::bytea
```

Unfortunately I don't think there is any way to invoke the `receive` function directly, due to its use of the `internal` pseudo-type.